# Talend, combine tWaitForFile and tFileList

Tags: etl, talend

I'm not so advanced in Talend, and I have got a job developed by a Talend expert which have a trick that i cannot understand, this is the tricky beginning of the job:
[The tricky beginning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dp1J.jpg)

The job will process any file exists in a specified folder, there is a producer process which write files continuously into the folder, so it have to process the already existing files and any new file will be created, the ammount of files is so huge and the target system is Linux.

I cant understand why he uses the tFileList while he can use only the tWaitForFile, it can retrieve existing and later created files.

Cordially.

Comment: This seems pretty subjective and I'm not sure what kind of objective answer you're looking for here. If that job is doing what I think it is and then waiting for a file to arrive in a folder and then grabbing everything in that folder and processing it rather than just the most recent file. I'd hazard a guess that it's then filtering out the old files which looks stupid. My old answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831756/talend-twaitforfile-insufficiency) should show you how to set a job up for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWaitForFile used to start file processing when there is files, the job should be run continiously but do nothing until TWaitForFile detect file in the directory, its simply a file-based trigger used as alternative for the trigger feature of the Entreprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

you are  right, tFileList or tWaitForFile component is sufficient to process exiting files and newly created file. But if you post job design or component property details for both the component then it will help to answer your question.